# inserting data into mysql from an html textboxes. using php/mysql

Tags: php

I can't see where i am going wrong, it just won't let me connect to the mysql database and i only get error message when trying to save details.?????? i think there may be a problem where it shows $sql for inserting the values into the table. the first part newstudent.php works, but sql.php does not work.

```
//new student.php
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h2>Your details</h2>
     <form name="frmdetails" action="sql.php" method="post">
        ID Number :
     <input name="txtid" type="text" />
        <br/>
    Password :
     <input name="txtpassword" type="text" />
        <br/>
    Date of Birth :
     <input name="txtdob" type="text" />
        <br/>
    First Name :
    <input name="txtfirstname" type="text" />
        <br/>
        Surname :
        <input name="txtlastname" type="text" />
    <br/>
        Number and Street :
    <input name="txthouse" type="text"   />
        <br/>
        Town :
        <input name="txttown" type="text"  />
    <br/>
        County :
    <input name="txtcounty" type="text"   />
        <br/>
         Country :
    <input name="txtcountry" type="text"   />
        <br/>
        Postcode :
        <input name="txtpostcode" type="text"   />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
   </html>

//sql.php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "20915184", "mysqluser"); 
 mysql_select_db("db5_20915184", $conn);

// If the form has been submitted

$id=$_POST['txtstudentid'];
$password=$_POST['txtpassword'];
$dob=$_POST['txtdob'];
$firstname=$_POST['txtfirstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['txtlastname'];
$house=$_POST['txthouse'];
$town=$_POST['txttown'];
$county=$_POST['txtcounty'];
$country=$_POST['txtcountry'];
$postcode=$_POST['txtpostcode'];



    // Build an sql statment to add the student details
    $sql="INSERT INTO student

(studentid,password,dob,firstname,lastname,house,town,county,country,postcode) VALUES

('$id','$password','$dob','$firstname','$lastname','$house','$town','$county','$country','$postcode')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if($result){
echo"<br/>Your details have been updated";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='Home.html'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: 20915184 is your db user or db password?

Comment: Note, that your script is vulnerable to tampering via SQL injection.  Escape all your `$_POST` input values with `mysql_real_escape_string()` as in `$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);`

Comment: If you're getting your ERROR message, `echo mysql_error()` to see what failed.

Comment: Another note on style & security --  it is not safe to store passwords in plain text in your database. Instead store a hash like `sha1($password)` in the database, and on subsequent logins, check that `sha1($password)` is equal to the value in the database.

Comment: pass value from javascript                                                                                like this-> var x=escape($('#xyz'.val()));                                                                       AND Receive value in PHP                                                                             like this ->$x=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['xyz']);      Then pass $x into sql query....                                                                             $sql = "INSERT INTO company_test (name, currency) VALUES ('ABC Widgets', '$x')";        Its worked for me ..

Answer (score 0):

The username comes before the password in mysql_connect();
Try running the sql statement in phpmyadmin and see if it works there!

Comment: the username is 20915184 and password is mysqluser

Answer (score 0):

With in your if else statement,  where you echo "ERROR", try printing mysql_error()  this would show that your mysql_connect() is wrong If the username/password combo is wrong.

To clean this up a bit,  Here is what the if/else should look like

```
if($result){
  echo"<br/>Your details have been updated";
  echo "<BR>";
  echo "<a href='Home.html'>Back to main page</a>";
} else {
  echo "There has been an error <br/>";
  print mysql_error();
}
```

EDIT :

Also,  Prevent sql injection with mysql_real_escape_string() on all posted values

Comment: Agreed. This will tell you why SQL rejected your insert. If it doesn't help you, post the results here.

Comment: i now get 'there has been an error duplicate entry " for key 1

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to duplicate some data in the table then.  Something that is set as a primary key is already in there.  example.  If you have your first name set as primary key, you can only use the first name one time.

Comment: i think the id is set to primary key

Comment: When testing this then, make sure that you are using a unique id number.  If you are entering it in and not making it an auto inc number, this will always have to be different as the database will not allow a duplicate primary key

Comment: i have tried using different id numbers, when putting it through the form. i also tried to check that mysql database is working, through putty and it is from there, but still shows duplicate data error message in php

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is incomplete, you must insert when the button is clicked also its important to check if a field isset before saving the field in the database also important to filter and sanitize user inputs before submitting. Learn to use prepared statements, with mysqli prepared or PDO whatever works for you, Also don't store passwords in plain text/md5 use password_hash() and password_verify()

Your code with mysqli prepared should look like :

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Your details</h2>
      <form name="frmdetails" action="sql.php" method="post">
         ID Number :
         <input name="txtid" type="text" />
         <br/>
         Password :
         <input name="txtpassword" type="text" />
         <br/>
         Date of Birth :
         <input name="txtdob" type="text" />
         <br/>
         First Name :
         <input name="txtfirstname" type="text" />
         <br/>
         Surname :
         <input name="txtlastname" type="text" />
         <br/>
         Number and Street :
         <input name="txthouse" type="text"   />
         <br/>
         Town :
         <input name="txttown" type="text"  />
         <br/>
         County :
         <input name="txtcounty" type="text"   />
         <br/>
         Country :
         <input name="txtcountry" type="text"   />
         <br/>
         Postcode :
         <input name="txtpostcode" type="text"   />
         <br/>
         <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**sql.php**

```
<?php



$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "20915184";
$password   = "mysqluser";
$dbname     = "db5_20915184";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$errors = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // submit button clicked


        // validate fields



        if (empty($_POST['txtstudentid'])) {

                echo "enter id";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $id = userData($_POST['txtstudentid']);

        }

        if (empty($_POST['txtpassword'])) {

                echo "enter password";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $password = userData($_POST['txtpassword']);

                $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //hashing password
        }

        if (empty($_POST['txtdob'])) {
                echo "enter date of birth";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $dob = userData($_POST['txtdob']);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['txtfirstname'])) {
                echo "enter first name";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $firstname = userData($_POST['txtfirstname']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['txtlastname'])) {

                echo "enter last name";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $lastname = userData($_POST['txtlastname']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['txthouse'])) {

                echo "enter house";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $house = userData($_POST['txthouse']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['txttown'])) {

                echo "enter town";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $town = userData($_POST['txttown']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['txtcounty'])) {

                echo "enter country";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $country = userData($_POST['txtcounty']);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['txtpostcode'])) {

                echo "enter post code";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $postcode = userData($_POST['txtpostcode']);
        }

        if ($errors <= 0) { //all fields are set no errors

                //start query


                //check if user id does not exist


                $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT studentid FROM students WHERE studentid = ?");
                $statement->bind_param('s', $id);
                $statment->execute();

                $statement->bind_result($studentID);

                if ($statement->num_rows == 1) {

                        echo "the student Id " . $studentID . " already registered please login";

                } else {


                        // no results then lets insert


                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO students (studentid,password,dob,firstname,lastname,house,town,country,postcode) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $id, $hash, $dob, $firstname, $lastname, $house, $town, $country, $postcode);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        echo "<p>Your Details have been updated<br> <a href=\"Home.html\">Back to main page";
                        $stmt->close();
                        $conn->close();



                }



        }






}

//filter userinput
function userData($data)
{

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
}
?>
```

There are many good tutorials on the net on this, hopes this will help, I'm also open to suggestions and corrections incase I missed something.

**> Question mark (?)(placeholder) is used to assign the value.In Prepared

> Statements we assign in the values in bind parameter function so that
>   our query is processed in secure way and prevent from SQL injections.**

In Prepared Statements we pass or attach the values to database query with the help of Bind Parameter function.

You have to attach all the variables whose value you want in your query with their appropriate Data Types just like we pass the 's' means the variable contains a string Data Type.

To execute the query in Prepared Statements you have to use execute() function with query object.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the parameter from your with the inside inside and put in an empty string. i.e

```
 VALUES('','$password','$dob',
```

etc etc

Comment: From the example given. A student or person entering in the data would supply studentID so you would not want to leave this blank.  I would guess it is not an auto inc number

Comment: How do you know. Perhaps it is a primary number. In fact, most probably it is.

Comment: | studentid | varchar(8)  | NO   | PRI | NULL
this is the data type for student id